# Segmentation fault while calling getch()

Tags: c++, ubuntu, console-application, curses, getch

I am trying to make a simple console program using curses on ubuntu, but each time I try to call getch and make it wait for input, when I input the input, it throws a segmentation fault. I did initialize the library using the initscr() function in another part of my code.

Here is the part of code throwing the segmentation fault :

```
int ch;
ch = getch();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Mindoo

EDIT:
After switching out the int for a char, I get the following warnings that revolve arround this piece of code right after the previously mentioned getch().

```
char ch;
  ch = getch();

  //Get xObject position
  int xObjectX = getXObject()->getPosX();
  int xObjectY = getXObject()->getPosY();

  switch (ch) {
    case KEY_LEFT:
      getXObject()->move(xObjectY, xObjectX--);
      break;

    case KEY_RIGHT:
      getXObject()->move(xObjectY, xObjectX++);
      break;

    case KEY_UP:
      getXObject()->move(xObjectY++, xObjectX);
      break;

    case KEY_DOWN:
      getXObject()->move(xObjectY--, xObjectX);
      break;

    case KEY_BACKSPACE:
      game->stop();
      break;
```

I get these warnings :

```
TestGameState.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void TestGameState::handleInput()’:
TestGameState.cpp:21:5: warning: case label value exceeds maximum value for type
     case KEY_LEFT:
     ^
TestGameState.cpp:25:5: warning: case label value exceeds maximum value for type
     case KEY_RIGHT:
     ^
TestGameState.cpp:29:5: warning: case label value exceeds maximum value for type
     case KEY_UP:
     ^
TestGameState.cpp:33:5: warning: case label value exceeds maximum value for type
     case KEY_DOWN:
     ^
TestGameState.cpp:37:5: warning: case label value exceeds maximum value for type
     case KEY_BACKSPACE:
```

Comment: That is obviously not enough to go on.  post a complete example.

Comment: Well, what else do you want me to post, thats pretty much everything I can post without posting my whole project folder.

Comment: This part of the code is __definitely not__ causing a segmentation fault.

Comment: As an aside, use `char ch` instead of `int ch`

Comment: Thats what I thought, but if I put a printw() before and after this part, the second one does not appear as the segfault appears first where as the first does appear on screen.

Comment: Actually it could be, @ABusyProgrammer, but it would be the result of bad Juju a lot earlier. For example, a crash over `ch = getch();` could be the visible manifestation of an eariler stack overflow.  Either way, all we can do with what's been provided is guess.

Comment: Guess #1: Did you correctly defrobble the Bugornic Atimeter?

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer I tried switching out the int for a char, and it got rid of the seg fault, but it spit out a lot of warnings.

Comment: What are the warnings?

Comment: "_in another part of my code_" What is this part of code?

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer see the edit in the question

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer `int ch;` is the correct line, `char ch;` is wrong.

Comment: May I ask, what is KEY_UP, and all the other variables causing the error? I have frankly never done game development in C++, so I cannot comment on the warnings

Comment: @n.m. Why should it be ing?

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer there are hundreds of questions on this site that deal with this exact blunder. `getch()` returns an `int`. Read the documentation.

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer KEY_UP and all the others are constants defined by curses that represent the arrow keys etc...

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer sorry we're talking about `getch()` not `getchar()`, my bad. `getch()` doesn't have hundreds of questions on this site. But it still returns an `int` just like `getchar()`, the same arguments ap[ply.

Comment: "if I put a printw() before and after this part" It's not a guaranteed way to locate the problem. Use a proper debugger. Also go back to `int ch`.

Comment: @n.m. I see. Well in that case, some other part of the code has to be causing the error.

Comment: @mindoo Use a debugger, it will help you more than using printf statements.

Answer (score 0):

That function is unlikely to be the cause.  How did you tell that line cause SF?

You may try:
1. use getchar instead
2. try not to use curses

Comment: I need curse to do the displaying. I realized that was the line causing the segfault by putting a printw("example") line on each end of that piece of code and it only displayed once.

Comment: Try to isolate problems. Like remove anything, just this like to see if crash still happen. Then add piece by piece.  Most likely, something instead of this caused the crash.

Comment: What do you mean, thats just what I did

Comment: Tryo to use a debugger, printing message is not a reliable way to find out the exact fault point.